# c-fortran interoperability - derived types with pointers

Tags: c, interop, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have long fortran code that has to be made usable from python. I decided to do Fortran->C->Python interface.

I got a problem: I have derived types within Fortran modules that contain

```
double precision, allocatable
```

type as members.

When trying to compile with ifort I get (with gfortran something similar):

```
Each component of a derived type with the BIND attribute shall be a nonpointer,         
nonallocatable data component with interoperable type and type parameters
```

This is actually with agreement with Intel compiler documentation and Fortran 2003 standard: point 15.2.5.

Is there any way to access Fortran "type" with allocatable or pointer inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Even the brand new [TS 29113](ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N1901-N1950/N1942.pdf)
does not offer a solution. It has the `TYPE(*)` but you have to know, how to decode the structure in C. You can do it by reverse engineering.

There is actually a macro for the size of the structure in the referenced TS. See `CFI_attribute_allocatable`. But the problem with dereferencing remains. There is a standard array descriptor proposed, but this TS is not yet supported by some compilers (notably by gfortran).

What is possible, is to just pass the pointer to the structure to a generic function such as `qsort`. Then you use just a piece of memory, that happens to contain also some pointer or allocatable descriptor, but C does not have to know about them.

Another possibility is to construct a derived type which holds only `type(c_ptr)`, instead of Fortran pointers and use `c_loc()` to fill them. Be sure to have only contiguous arrays then.

Comment: For each instance of object whose type is my derived type, I know the actual size of the arrays included. They may be different for each instance. I could handle the dereference. Perhaps I do not undestand the problem. For me the Pointer is just an adress in the memory, and something like
struct{
int *a
int *b
int *c
};

is 3*sizeof(int *) bytes large, which usually evaluates to 24 bytes (this value might be equal to only 12 bytes, but it may be determined for each computer once and for all).

What is different in the Fortran? The pointer in Fortran is much different than in C ?

Comment: Pointers in Fortran and even more allocatable components are more, then just addresses. They can point to noncontiguous arrays, for example.