# interoperability between Cpython and fortran linked lists

Tags: python, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have a fortran linked list that is roughly like

```
type :: node
    type(node), pointer :: next => null()
    integer :: value
end type node
```

I would ideally like to interact with this using Cpython. I have used fortran subroutines with python a lot using the f2py program to create the shared object. However, f2py can not be used with derived types.

My question is simply whether it possible at all to access something like a linked list in Fortran with cpython. I presume I need to follow the fortran to c to cpython route. However, I've read that for a fortran derived type to interoperable with c "Each component  must have interoperable type and type parameters, must not be a pointer, and must not be allocatable." Likewise, the post [c-fortran interoperability - derived types with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748276/c-fortran-interoperability-derived-types-with-pointers) seems to confirm this.

I was wondering if anyone knows if it is definitely not possible to access a linked list in fortran from cpython. If it is possible, even if indirectly or in a round-about way, I would be grateful to hear more.

thank you,
Mark

Comment: I'm not sure that the implementation of fortran pointers is standardized between compilers -- So I'm doubtful that you'll be able to do this.  If you only need 1 linked list, you could put one in a module and have a bunch of functions use that module to access it -- That's pretty hacky of course.  Also note that python pretty much makes the necessity for a linked-list a non-issue ... You can always convert a python list to a numpy array and pass that around (but I understand that working with legacy code might make that difficult)...

Comment: That won't be C interoparable as it is. You could use `type(cptr)` as pointer to point to the next structure, but then you would have to convert inside Fortran this pointer via `c_f_pointer()` to be useable (and with `f_c_pointer()` back if needed), so rather a pain...

Comment: By far the easiest would probably be to create an array based on the linked list and pass that to python. But that would be a quite heavy operation. Directly accessing your existing list from C is possible, but not in a portable way (You would need to reverse engineer how the fortran pointer is represented, and how the derived type is laid out in memory. And then hope it doesn't change in the next compiler release).

Comment: Armed with the information provided in these comments (thank you to mgilson, Baliant Aradi and amaurea), I am going to continue to seek a solution or a workaround to this problem. I will post back if and when I find something conclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has Bálint Aradi already mentioned  in the comments, the node is not interoperable with C in it's current form. For that you need to change fortran pointers into C pointers, but that makes it extremely painful to use inside fortran itself. The most elegant solution I could come up with was putting the C interoperable type inside a fortran type and holding separate versions of C and fortran pointers.

The implementation is show below, where I've also defined convenience functions to be used inside fortran to allocate, deallocate and initialize the nodes.

```
module node_mod

    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none

    ! the C interoperable type
    type, bind(c) :: cnode
        type(c_ptr) :: self = c_null_ptr
        type(c_ptr) :: next = c_null_ptr
        integer(c_int) :: value
    end type cnode

    ! the type used for work in fortran
    type :: fnode
        type(cnode) :: c
        type(fnode), pointer :: next => null()
    end type fnode

contains

recursive function allocate_nodes(n, v) result(node)

    integer, intent(in) :: n
    integer, optional, intent(in) :: v
    type(fnode), pointer :: node
    integer :: val

    allocate(node)
    if (present(v)) then
        val = v
    else
        val = 1
    end if
    node%c%value = val
    if (n > 1) then
        node%next => allocate_nodes(n-1, val+1)
    end if

end function allocate_nodes

recursive subroutine deallocate_nodes(node)

    type(fnode), pointer, intent(inout) :: node
    if (associated(node%next)) then
        call deallocate_nodes(node%next)
    end if
    deallocate(node)

end subroutine deallocate_nodes

end module node_mod
```

As you can see, there's an extra "%c" needed to access the "value" element, which is a bit of a nuisance. To use the previously defined routines inside python to retrieve the linked list, C interoperable wrappers must be defined and C pointers must be linked.

```
module node_mod_cinter

    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    use, non_intrinsic :: node_mod

    implicit none

contains

recursive subroutine set_cptr(node)

    type(fnode), pointer, intent(in) :: node

    node%c%self = c_loc(node)
    if (associated(node%next)) then
        node%c%next = c_loc(node%next%c)
        call set_cptr(node%next)
    end if

end subroutine set_cptr

function allocate_nodes_citer(n) bind(c, name="allocate_nodes") result(cptr)

    integer(c_int), value, intent(in) :: n
    type(c_ptr) :: cptr
    type(fnode), pointer :: node

    node => allocate_nodes(n)
    call set_cptr(node)
    cptr = c_loc(node%c)

end function allocate_nodes_citer

subroutine deallocate_nodes_citer(cptr) bind(c, name="deallocate_nodes")

    type(c_ptr), value, intent(in) :: cptr
    type(cnode), pointer :: subnode
    type(fnode), pointer :: node

    call c_f_pointer(cptr, subnode)
    call c_f_pointer(subnode%self, node)
    call deallocate_nodes(node)

end subroutine deallocate_nodes_citer

end module node_mod_cinter
```

The "*_nodes_citer" routines simply deal with the different pointer types and the set_cptr subroutine links the C pointers inside the C interoperable type according to the fortran pointers. I've added the node%c%self element so that the fortran pointer could be recovered and used for proper deallocation, but if you're not too much concerned about that, then its not strictly needed.

This code needs to be compiled as a shared library to be used by other programs. I used the following command with gfortran on my linux box.

```
gfortran -fPIC -shared -o libnode.so node.f90
```

Finally, the python code to allocate a list of 10 nodes, print out the node%c%value of each of them and then deallocate everything again. Additionally, the memory locations of fortran and C nodes are also shown.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ctypes
from ctypes import POINTER, c_int, c_void_p
class Node(ctypes.Structure):
    pass
Node._fields_ = (
        ("self", c_void_p),
        ("next", POINTER(Node)),
        ("value", c_int),
        )

def define_function(res, args, paramflags, name, lib):

    prot = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(res, *args)
    return prot((name, lib), paramflags)

def main():

    import os.path

    libpath = os.path.abspath("libnode.so")
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libpath)

    allocate_nodes = define_function(
            res=POINTER(Node),
            args=(
                c_int,
                ),
            paramflags=(
                (1, "n"),
                ),
            name="allocate_nodes",
            lib=lib,
            )

    deallocate_nodes = define_function(
            res=None,
            args=(
                POINTER(Node),
                ),
            paramflags=(
                (1, "cptr"),
                ),
            name="deallocate_nodes",
            lib=lib,
            )

    node_ptr = allocate_nodes(10)

    n = node_ptr[0]
    print "value", "f_ptr", "c_ptr"
    while True:
        print n.value, n.self, ctypes.addressof(n)
        if n.next:
            n = n.next[0]
        else:
            break

    deallocate_nodes(node_ptr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Executing this gives me the following output:

```
value f_ptr c_ptr
1 15356144 15356144
2 15220144 15220144
3 15320384 15320384
4 14700384 14700384
5 15661152 15661152
6 15661200 15661200
7 15661248 15661248
8 14886672 14886672
9 14886720 14886720
10 14886768 14886768
```

It's interesting to note that both node types start at the same memory locations, so node%c%self was not really needed, but this is only because I was careful with the type definitions and this really should not be counted on.

And there you have it. Even without having to deal with linked lists it's quite a hassle, but ctypes are vastly more powerful and robust that f2py. Hope some good comes out of this.

Comment: Wow! This is a brilliant answer and I'm ashamed that I had not noticed this post before today (almost a month later). I had just assumed that this task was more or less practically impossible. Thank you for the comprehensiveness of your answer. I have run the code on linux and it worked straight out of the box. Even though the use of fortran linked lists in cpython must be indirect, this is a price worth paying for what I want. I will be studying your code intensely in the future. Many many thanks.